# What do the different representations for roads mean?

Tags: google-maps

In Google Maps, different roads are drawn in different ways.

For example, in the following screenshot of Google Maps of an area, why are the drawings of roads in the black, red, green, and blue boxes different?

What do they mean respectively?

[image: Road examples]

Answer (score 4):

In your blue box: a paved walking/biking trail.

Green box: an unpaved hiking trail.

Red box: a road.

Black box: property lines.

(If you switch between map and satellite view, you can see the correspondence.)

Comment: Thanks. What does "property lines" mean? What do they look like? Are they open to and walkable by pedestrains? Why are some of them parallel to some roads?

Comment: Property lines divide legal properties. They exist in the county's records of land organization and ownership. They do not exist in the real world although there are often fences along property lines.

Comment: I don't own any land in the map. Is it legally acceptable If I walk along a property line?

Comment: If you are sufficiently thin, the two land owners could not tell if you're trespassing. You might have to walk atop some fences, bushes, and other inconveniences.